# I want to autofill an Excel row using a variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I currently I have a Excel sheet and what I want it to do, is lookup data that is provided on another sheet and autofill it in regards to it. I'll try to explain what I mean below.

[image: excel spreadsheet]

So for example columns `1`, `2` and `3` would be empty, after a code 1 is typed into column `123` I'd want columns `1`, `2` and `3` to update to the values provided. It would link up to another sheet shown below and I'd like it to expand dynamically so as if more data were to be added to the below sheet it would still update.

[image: data]

I apologise if this sounds confusing but I've tried looking everywhere for functions that will be able to help me out. The only solution I've gotten is a VERY long nested if statement which I'm certain is the worst way to approach this.

first table is called "Autofill" 
the second table is "Details"

the worksheet to be filled is called "Sheet1"
the one containing the details is called "Details"

Comment: Are they both list object tables? what are the table names? what worksheets are they on?

Comment: yes they are, the first one is called "Autofill" the second table is "Details" the worksheet to be filled is called Sheet1, the one containing the details is called Details.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it simply using vlookup on the other sheet and matching the rows

Comment: You could also consider an Index-Match-Match if you want to dynamically match rows and columns. VLOOKUP is a lot slower and won't allow a column AND a row match.